# Hibernate How To Save ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I have two entities `Equipement` and `Company` like this:

```
public class Equipement{
  String type ;
  Company company ;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Company getCompany(){
    return this.company ;
  }
}

public class Company{
  // fields getters setters ..
}
```

Each `Equipement` is bought from a `Company`, I need to create the `Company` and then inject it to the `Equipement`

```
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession() ;
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction() ;

Equipement equipement = new Equipement() ;
Company company = new company() ;
equipement.setCompany(company) ;
session.save(equipement) ;

tx.commit() ;
session.close() ;
```

and that give me an exception

```
TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.marsamaroc.mmapp.domain.Company
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class Company 
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Equipement> getEquipements() { ... }
}
```

and

```
...
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession() ;
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction() ;

Equipement equipement = new Equipement() ;
Company company = new company() ;
equipement.setCompany(company) ;

// Save should cascade (i.e. "equipment" should be saved too).
session.save(company) ;

tx.commit() ;
session.close() ;
...
```

Btw, in English, it's "equipment", without the extra 'e' (in case you care!).

Comment: What if i have to save many `Equipement` entries with the same `Company`, I tried this but it's only saving the "company".

Comment: Have you got `Cascade.ALL` set in `Company` (see updated answer)?

Comment: Also, I don't think having `Cascade.ALL` on the `Equipement` side of the association is what you want (could be wrong though).